Change different page header in word document with OpenXML in C#
I have to modify the header of a word document. Header from page 2 onwards is different from the first page and both contain the same table.
I'm using the following code:
    var headerparts = doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.ToList(); 
    foreach (HeaderPart headerpart in headerparts)
    {
       var headers = headerpart.Header.ToList();
       try
       {
          foreach (Table table in headers)
          {
             table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1).Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(1).RemoveAllChildren();
             table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1).Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(1).Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("new text"))));
          }        
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

It works for the first page only, while on the 2nd page it doesn't have any effect.
Why this? How to modify the headers for subsequent pages?
Thanks to anyone.

I tink you need this: Replace the header in a word processing document, some use of headerPart ?

I just tried that; I get 3 different IDs (the document has 3 pages), however, the table is present only in 1 of them; all others have just Paragraphs.

Got it working like this:
MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
        var hdp = mainPart.HeaderParts.ToList();
        foreach (HeaderPart hd in hdp)
        {
            Header h = hd.Header;
            var  childs = h.Elements<Table>().ToList();
            try
            {
                foreach (Table table in childs)
                {
                    table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1).Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(1).RemoveAllChildren();
                    table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1).Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(1).Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("new test"))));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {  }
        }

